# How to print messages in Custom Exception?

Tags: java

I'm new to exceptions and am a bit confused at getMessage() and super(customMessage). Please forgive me if it sounds rather ridiculous...

Part of my try catch code is here:

```
try{
        sc.buyASong();
    } catch (CardEmptyException e){
        System.out.println("Caught error: " +e.getMessage() );
    } catch (CardNotActivatedException e){
        System.out.println("Caught error: " +e.getMessage() );
    }
```

And I want to print "Caught error: Card not activated"
or "Caught error: No more songs on the card". And my custom exception is like this

```
class CardNotActivatedException extends Exception{
public CardNotActivatedException(){
    super("Card not activated");
    }
}
class CardEmptyException extends Exception{
    public CardEmptyException(){
        super("No more songs on the card");
    }
}
```

But when I run it, it prints

```
com.example.CardNotActivatedException: Card not activated
```

and "Caught error: ----" is not printed out as well. Is there something that I am understanding wrongly? Because it looks like I am fundamentally wrong and I'm not quite sure where my misunderstanding is...?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code you think you are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're catching the CardEmptyException ?
Did you forget to save your code?

Anyway, I suggest you change your approach, and use a constructor method receiving a String object. You can keep a default costructor with a default message, but also use somthing like this one:

```
public MyCustomException(String arg0) {
    super(arg0);
}
```

Then, whenever you call this exception, you can call passa the message you want to.